# Raster displays in wrong location and scale on QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I have a magnetometry raster that I'm trying to project alongside other geophysics data. My advisor who helped me collect the data and who processed its sent me a PNG with CRS data. He told me the CRS was Lat Long but not which CRS specifically. He was able to get it to display fine over a Google Satellite layer though I don't know what program he used.

I've tried projecting the data in every WGS 84 available but it always displays the raster in the South Atlantic near Africa, even though the data was collected north of London. I've also discovered the raster is in the wrong scale. When I measure it with the measuring tool it comes to thousands of hectares when the actual area was only about 1.3 hectares.

Is the problem maybe that the coordinates are reversed? The raster is right-side-up but I don't know if perhaps it's projection is based on a single anchor point. I've noticed when I mix up lat/long when uploading a delimited text layer it sends the data to the same general area, off the coast of West Africa though not that exact spot. Also the change in scale doesn't happen with a vector grid.

For reference I'm running QGIS 3.22.1-Białowieża

Comment: Ask them to provide a world-file. Also, the data is probably in a degree based CRS, have you tried setting the CRS to EPSG 4326?

Comment: I can ask. He's hard to get ahold of at the moment so I was hoping there'd be a way to sort it out just based on the file itself. 

I just tried EPSG 4326 again, same result.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: How are you getting coordinate numbers for a PNG? PNG files themselves can't have any coordinates or CRS - have you got them in another file or email or something? What numbers have you actually got?

Comment: There's also a png.aux.xml and a klm file in the same folder. Could it be pulling CRS data from one of those? What would normally happen if you tried to apply a CRS to an image with no coordinate data? Would it just send it to a default point? Maybe that's what's happening.